# Combining Statistical Sets

Tags: statistics

I am doing an analysis of employee performance.

And have two questions regarding sample size. (All calculations come from Survey Monkey’s Sample Size Calculator)

Say an employee performs 500 tasks per month and I want to review this employee’s performance.

If I want a confidence level of 95% and can accept a 10% margin of error then I would need to review 81 tasks. However if the population size was 1500 the sample size required for the same confidence level (95%) and margin of error (10%) would be 91.

If I'm willing to do quarterly as opposed to monthly reviews then the number of reviews drops precipitously.

QUESTION 1: Can I then assume that if I do my review quarterly as opposed to monthly that a sample size of 91 would suffice?

QUESTION 2: Can one aggregate confidence level and margin of error? For example in month one I accept a lower level of confidence and margin of error than I would otherwise want; but over time as they are aggregated I get a higher and higher confidence level.

The conceptual model is that combining them over time is identical to doing a “quarterly; “semi-annual” and “annual” analysis.

Mthly

> Population: 500
>
> Confidence Level: 80%
>
> Margin of Error: 10%
>
> Sample Size: 38

Over three months the aggregate would be a population of 1500 and a sample size of 114. This would give me a confidence level of 90 and a margin of error of 7.4. See below:

Quarterly

> Population: 1500
>
> Confidence Level: 90%
>
> Margin of Error: 7.4%
>
> Sample Size: 114

Over six months the aggregate would be a population of 3000 and a sample size of 228.

> Semi-Annually Population: 3000
>
> Confidence Level: 90%
>
> Margin of Error: 5.23%
>
> Sample Size: 228

Thus, if my assumptions are correct, as I aggregate these reviews I increase my confidence level and decrease my margin of error.

The purpose for this would allow me to do a more thorough weekly and monthly analysis on new employees by reducing the review load on long-term employees.

Comment: You are asking the wrong board. You should be asking this on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), not stack overflow

Comment: @rhavelka - I was wondering about that, but I saw other statistical questions here in stackoverflow.

Comment: I think most are tied to a language though like R or python or something within machine learning or a ui with customized statistics. This seems like pure mathematics.